# Can anyone help me figure out what type of bug this is?

Tags: insect

In the past weeks I've had these bugs show up.  First on my dinner table and now on a book shelf.  I've sprayed bug spray and then vinegar on the table itself.  But it doesn't seem to deter them.

[image: up close view]

[image: normal view]

Comment: Have you considered posting this on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com)? They are good at species identification. They even have [a tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a bug guy come out.  They were white, fuzzy, super tiny almost spider\ant types.  Turned out they were baby ghost ants.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't see it well enough to be sure what it is.  What type of insecticide did you try to use?  I would start with permethryn (Permanone) as it is very effective, has a mild odor and is one of the safest to use (synthesized plant extract).